# Javascript or jQuery is not loading iFrame after 999th Row in Table on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am facing weird issue when loading iframe with javascript or jquery on click event..

I have search form which shows result set and each rows has a unique id and each row has corresponding iframe which is display:none by default.

When user click on plus icon it loads iframe source and remove display none to corresponding iframe row. My code is working fine till Row-999 but after that when user click on plus icon, it add source to iframe, even change plus(+) icon to minus(-) but still it is not loading iFrame and not showing perticular row. And no error is showing in console also. I don't know why it is not working after 999th Row.
Please Help me..

```
<tr>
    <td class="resultListItem">
      <a style="cursor:hand; text-decoration: none;" class="plus-anchor" href="#row-1045" data-src="http://localhost/l58/public/cic/tab/company-info?mode=iframe&amp;active=tab1&amp;addressid=251856&amp;siteuseid=276003&amp;siteusecode=BILL_TO&amp;customerid=11728&amp;orgid=83" onclick="toggleTabsLoad(1045);">
            <div onclick="changeSymbol('symbol1045')" id="symbol1045" class="plus-icon">+</div>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td class="resultListItem">CONNECT SINGLE SALE</td>
    <td class="resultListItem">123123</td>
    <td class="resultListItem">1110</td>
    <td class="resultListItem">58 DISCOVERY</td>
    <td class="resultListItem">IRVINE</td>
    <td class="resultListItem">US</td>
</tr>
<tr id="TR1045" style="display:none;">
    <td colspan="7">
        <iframe id="row-1045" style="width: 100%;" border-top="1px solid #A9A9A9;" frameborder="0" height="150px"></iframe>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my javascript code below...

```
function toggleTabsLoad(id) {
        obj = document.getElementById('TR' + id);
        var source = document.querySelector("a[href='#row-" + id + "']").getAttribute('data-src');
        console.log(source);  // giving output in all rows
        frame = document.getElementById('row-' + id);
        console.log(frame);  // giving output in all rows
        frame.src=source;

        if (obj.style.display == 'none') {
            obj.style.display = '';
        } else {
            obj.style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
```

I also tried with jQuery but I am getting same behavior...

```
$(function() {
    var plus = $('.plus-anchor');
    plus.on('click', function() {
        var row = $(this).attr('href'),
        source = $(this).data('src');
        $('iframe' + row).attr('src', source);  
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't consider this source "credible", but others have noted [**Chrome only allows 1000 iframes**](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/25091/chrome-only-allows-1000-iframes). I'd say it's doing you a favor :) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe): *"Because each browsing context is a complete document environment, every <iframe> in a page requires increased memory and other computing resources. While theoretically you can use as many <iframe>s as you like, check for performance problems."*

Comment: Rather than creating 1,000 empty iframes when the page loads, create them when the row is expanded. You'd only run into this issue if the user expanded 1,000 rows.

Comment: Thanks Santi, it seems like Chrome only allows 1000 iframes at a time because its working fine in edge browser.